# Updating python kivy widgets - from outside of a class - good practice?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a python kivy gui with a `Switch` widget and a `Label` widget.

I want the `Label` widget (`status_label`) to indicate the status of the `Switch` widget (`switch_no_1` ), ie if `switch_no_1`  is on `status_label` should read *Current switch 1 status: the switch is on* and if `switch_no_1` is off `status_label` should read `Current switch 1 status: the switch is off`.

**The code below works** but the problem's that the only way I've been able to update `status_label` is by defining it as a class level variable instead of defining it with `self`. **So my question is, is this an acceptable approach or is there some other way of doing it that is better practice?**

Initially I did try to define `status_label` with self (`self.status_label`) and define `switch1_callback` as a method of the `NewSwitch` class (`def switch1_callback(self, switchObject, switchValue):` ...), but I can see why that threw me an error (`NameError: name 'switch1_callback' is not defined`).

Thanks for any help guys!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch

class NewSwitch(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewSwitch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size=(800, 800)

        NewSwitch.status_label = Label(text = 'Current switch 1 status: the switch is off',  pos=(100, 100), size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 780)) 
        self.add_widget(self.status_label)  

        self.switch_no_1 = Switch(active = False, pos=(125, 50), size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50))               
        self.add_widget(self.switch_no_1)                   
        self.switch_no_1.bind(active = switch1_callback)        
        
def switch1_callback(switchObject, switchValue):
    if(switchValue):
        NewSwitch.status_label.text = 'Current switch 1 status: the switch is on'
    else:
        NewSwitch.status_label.text = 'Current switch 1 status: the switch is off'

class SwitchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return NewSwitch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     SwitchApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve your problem is to use the capabilities of the kivy language. It provides the functionality that you need. Here is a modified version of your code that uses `kv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv = '''
<NewSwitch>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 800, 800
    Label:
        text: 'Current switch 1 status: the switch is on' if sw.active else 'Current switch 1 status: the switch is off'
        pos: 100, 100
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size[0], 780
    Switch:
        id: sw
        pos: 125, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 50
'''


class NewSwitch(FloatLayout):
    pass


class SwitchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return NewSwitch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchApp().run()
```